# magento .. can't run install script

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to run install script for my module and this is the first time for me, but it's not running and I can find my module in core_resource table.
the module version is:

```
<Mdg_Gift>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
 </Mdg_Gift>
```

and the installer name is:

> mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

I found this code area in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
$resModel   = (string)$this->_connectionConfig->model;
$modName    = (string)$this->_moduleConfig[0]->getName();

$filesDir   = Mage::getModuleDir('sql', $modName) . DS . $this->_resourceName;
 if (!is_dir($filesDir) || !is_readable($filesDir)) {
 return array();
 }
```

and printed out `$filesDir` and it's value was:

> G:\XAMPP\XAMPP\htdocs\citruss\app\code\ \Mdg\Gift\sql\mdg_gift_setup

the path is wrong and missing local codepool, I don't know what I should do.
any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**update**
config.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mdg_Gift>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mdg_Gift>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mdg_gift>
                <class>Mdg_Gift_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mdg_gift_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mdg_gift>
            <mdg_gift_mysql4>
                <class>Mdg_Gift_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <entity>
                        <table>mdg_gift_entity</table>
                    </entity>
                    <item>
                        <table>mdg_gift_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <type>
                        <table>mdg_gift_type</table>
                    </type>
                </entities>
            </mdg_gift_mysql4>
        </models>

        <blocks>
            <mdg_gift>
                <class>Mdg_Gift_Block</class>
            </mdg_gift>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <mdg_gift>
                <class>Mdg_Gift_Helper</class>
            </mdg_gift>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <mdg_gift_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mdg_Gift</module>
                    <class>Mdg_Gift_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_gift_setup>

            <mdg_gift_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_gift_write>

            <mdg_gift_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_gift_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mdg_gift>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mdg_Gift</module>
                    <frontName>gift</frontName>
                </args>
            </mdg_gift>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

also I can't route to IndexController.php file is there any mistake in my code
and here is my IndexController.php file:

```
<?php
class Mdg_Gift_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'This is our test controller';
    }

}
```

/app/etc/modules/Mdg_Gift.xml :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <mdg_gift>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </mdg_gift>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: any help, any idea???
if you need more details to help just let me know and will update the question.

Comment: Thank you for your response .. please have a look.

Comment: post the module file `Mdg_Gift.xml` found in `app/etc/modules/`

Comment: have a look please ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your etc/modules make the module name capital i.e.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mdg_Gift>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mdg_Gift>
    </modules>
</config>
```